# Spring 3 JDBC transaction manager not working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring 3, MYSQL 5.5, tomcat 6. In my app i have 3 DAO methods executing one after another inside a service class method.

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = {
            Exception.class, RuntimeException.class })
   myService(){
      try {
         dao1.delete();
         dao1.update();
         dao1.save();
      } catch(){}
   }

Dao1 -
delete() throws exp1{ ---- some code ----}
save() throws exp1{ ---- some code ----}
update() throws exp2{ ---- some code ----}
```

Now even if an exception is raised my transaction gets committed, like if update() raise an exception delete() and save() doesn't get rolledback. I tried looking into spring logs and i can see it has committed transaction after exception

```
20:00:29,071 DEBUG SQLErrorCodesFactory:198 - Looking up default SQLErrorCodes for DataSource [org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource@44755866]
20:00:29,078 DEBUG SQLErrorCodesFactory:216 - Database product name cached for DataSource [org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource@44755866]: name is 'MySQL'
20:00:29,079 DEBUG SQLErrorCodesFactory:174 - SQL error codes for 'MySQL' found
20:00:29,081 DEBUG SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator:399 - Translating SQLException with SQL state '42S02', error code '1146', message [Table 'xxx.xxxx' doesn't exist]; SQL was [DELETE FROM xxxx WHERE xxxx=?] for task [PreparedStatementCallback]
20:00:29,086 DEBUG xxxServiceImpl:1022 - Returning result after deleting product : xxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx.xxx.ResultVO Object {Result: false, Error code: 1016, Error text: Error while deleting data. Please try again later}
20:00:29,094 DEBUG DataSourceTransactionManager:752 - Initiating transaction commit
20:00:29,097 DEBUG DataSourceTransactionManager:264 - Committing JDBC transaction on Connection [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxx?autoReconnect=true, UserName=root@localhost, MySQL-AB JDBC Driver]
20:00:29,113 DEBUG DataSourceTransactionManager:322 - Releasing JDBC Connection [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxx?autoReconnect=true, UserName=root@localhost, MySQL-AB JDBC Driver] after transaction
20:00:29,115 DEBUG DataSourceUtils:332 - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
```

If i put @Transactionl before DAO methods, transaction gets rolledback but i am getting 500 error, stating that transaction is already marked for rollback. Am i missing something here?

Comment: You know that by default, transactions only roll back on unchecked exceptions, right?

Comment: yep, this is why i have rollbackFor = {Exception.class, RuntimeException.class } to make it work for checked exceptions

Comment: Is there an other Transaction within the daos?

Comment: No, there is no transaction within DAO's. They are simple Spring JDBC DAO using SQL statements. Also earlier i was using tomcat for database connection pool(JNDI lookup in spring), now i have converted it to DriverManagerDataSource(spring) but still issue is there.

Comment: is it the try{}catch() block which is not allow spring to know that it has to roll back the transaction?

Comment: so far i have concluded that it is JDBCTemplate which cause issue. All my DAO methods use  JDBCTemplate, although i have had DataSourceTransactionManager injected in dataSource bean inside my configuration file and JDBCtemplate is derived from there.

Comment: What about the `autoCommit` attribute of your JDBC connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `try {} catch {}` block.

The transaction rollback will happen only if the exception is thrown back to the caller from the method.

In your case you are silently killing the exception using a empty `try..catch` block, so the exception is never propagated to the transaction manager, so the transaction manger never get the signal to rollback.

In case of annotating the `dao`, when the exception is thrown from the dao layer, the transaction proxy surrounding the dao method marks the attached transaction (created by the service layer) as rollback only, then when the control is returned from the service layer the transaction manager tries to commit the changes but finds that it is marked as read-only. That is why the error is coming.